# Photo check to which album/s a photo belongs to

Tags: photos

I am trying to create smart albums backwards. I deleted all my albums and created a new folder with a new smart album.

I want the photos to match this criteria

- the date capture between a range (is working)
- that the photo is not in another album (this condition is failing)

[image]

I don't have the photo in other album, but the photo get hidden. I am not totally sure, but it seems it is related with the fact that the photos were not taken with an iphone. How can I check and remove the other album/s the photo belongs to?